# In robotframework is it possible to pass the --outputdir as a variable

Tags: python, robotframework

When running the tests and specifying an output directory one can do this `pybot -d /name-of-folder test.robot`.

Is it possible for the test.robot file to catch this input when running the test?

To better illustrate, I am logging the results of a test to a csv file but this csv file lives in the root dir of my tests. I am not always using the same `-d` folder to store my reports and I want to know if there is a way to catch that option within the test, something like `${outputdir}` for example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is documented in the robot framework user guide, in the section titled [Automatic Variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#automatic-variables). The name of the variable is `${OUTPUT DIR}`, and it contains an absolute path to the output directory. You can also use `${OUTPUT FILE}` if you need the full path to the output file.

Comment: Thank you. Exactly what I was looking for.